# Simplest way to mix anonymous conditions with IO

Tags: haskell

How to avoid boilerplate assignments like `doesExist <- doesDirectoryExist path` and `case doesExist of ...` within IO?

Is there a more idiomatic way than this?

```
import System.Directory
import System.Environment

main = do
  path:_ <- getArgs
  doesDirectoryExist path >>= cond
    (putStrLn $ path ++ " Exists")
    (putStrLn $ path ++ " Does not exist")

cond b c a = if a then b else c
```

Comment: BTW, `cond` is `flip bool` if you import `Data.Bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LambdaCase` is applicable here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import System.Directory
import System.Environment

main = do
  path:_ <- getArgs    

  doesDirectoryExist path >>= \case
    True -> putStrLn $ path ++ " Exists"
    _    -> putStrLn $ path ++ " Does not exist"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or same with "if":

```
doesDirectoryExist path >>= \x ->
 if x then (putStrLn "Exists") else putStrLn ("Does not")
```